# Typing a spreading function based in its original types

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
type TypeA = {
  type: 'typeA';
  foo: number;
  typeB: TypeB;
};

type TypeB = {
  type: 'typeB';
  bar: number;
};

type IntersectionType = TypeA & TypeB;

const func = (val: TypeA): IntersectionType => {
  return { ...val, ...val.typeB };
};
```

but I get the error

`The intersection 'IntersectionType' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.`

Is there a way to correctly type the function based on `TypeA` and `TypeB`?

`TypeA` and `TypeB` are auto-generated so I can't change them.

Comment: What do you want the union's `type` property to be? `'typeA' | 'typeB'`? `string`?

Comment: I don't really care for that property, both are fine. In this example the type would always be ```'typeB'```, which is fine.

Comment: Do you intend the result to have a `typeB` property? (It will as the function is currently written.)

Comment: Maybe something like `type UnionType = Omit<TypeA, 'type'> & Omit<TypeB, 'type'> & { type: string };`

Comment: That's it, thank you so much!

Comment: You know that `&` is an intersection, not a union, right? `|` is the union operator. Why not `type UnionType = TypeA | TypeB`, if you're really looking for a union?

Comment: Changed type name to ```IntersectionType``` for clarity